# Custom Form with Socialaccount in Django-allauth

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

I'm trying to modify the social account (in my case with Google) sign-up using django-allauth.

What I would like to achieve is to have the user click my "Sign-up with Google" button, but after Google login (on the callback) I would like to present the user with a consent form (regarding rules/GDPR) which he needs to submit before finalising the procedure.

Here's my form:

```
// landing/forms.py
from allauth.socialaccount.forms import SignupForm

class GoogleSignUpForm(SignupForm):
    privacy_policy = forms.BooleanField(
        required=True,
        label=_('I accept the privacy policy and rules '),
        help_text=_('You need to accept this to proceed with setting-up your account')
    )



    def __init__(self, sociallogin=None, **kwargs):
        super(GoogleSignUpForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        terms_and_conditions = reverse_lazy('privacy')
        self.fields['privacy_policy'].label = mark_safe(_(
            "I have read and agree with the "
            "<a href='%s'>Terms and Conditions</a>")) % (
                                                  terms_and_conditions)

    def save(self):
        user = super(GoogleSignUpForm, self).save()
        return user
```

I have the following setting in my base.py setting file:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS = {'signup': 'landing.forms.GoogleSignUpForm'}
```

And yet - the import line `from allauth.socialaccount.forms import SignupForm` is giving me the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing form class landing.forms: "cannot import name 'BaseSignupForm'"
```

Why is this happening and how to make this work?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

In our case this was caused by a custom `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS`. Using the default class and only setting `ACCOUNT_FORMS` instead solved the issue.